# Json String parse into Dictionary key value pairs c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, data-conversion

I am trying the convert my json string into dictionary but could not successful.

```
    {
  "healths": [
    {
      "serviceName": "UserMgt",
      "subService": [
        {
          "subServiceName": "Base",
          "status": 10
        },
        {
          "subServiceName": "Url",
          "description": "Url is bad",
          "status": 10
        },
        {
          "subServiceName": "Configuration",
          "status": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "serviceName": "ConfigurationMgt",
      "subService": [
        {
          "subServiceName": "url",
          "description": "urlis OK!",
          "status": 2
        },
        {
          "subServiceName": "Configuration Db",
          "status": 2
        }
      ]
    }
}...and so son
```

So, as you see we have a service name, and based on that we have subserviceName then again service name and subservicename.Basiclly i want to convert this into dictionary as a key-value pair so that based on the key(service) we have values subservice(again a key value pair).

I tried many things but does not get a proper result.
like for example using newtonsoft nuget.

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(formattedJson);
Dictionary<string, object> dictObj = jsonObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
foreach(var kv in dictObj)
{
  Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + "::::" + kv.Value);
}
```

In this scenario I am getting output like key as a healths and every thing as a value.
Can anyone please help me regarding this.The Json and c# is new for me.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What is value for subservice?

Comment: So, you want a dictionary, where every key is string and value is another dictionary with subservices?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are guaranteed to have the described structure, you can deserialize to `JObject` and use [LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)'s `ToDictionary` to process it:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json)["healths"]
    .ToDictionary(
        s => s["serviceName"].ToString(), 
        s => s["subService"]
            .ToDictionary(ss => ss["subServiceName"].ToString(), ss => ss["status"].ToString()));
```

Where you can change `ss => ss["status"].ToString()` to select what is actually needed as `subService` value.

Comment: The only thing I need to do that if we require based on subserviceName can we have two values.I mean for the current conversion we have 1 subServiceNameas "Url" and we have status as 10 but. if we want the description value as well with the same subserviceName as per my JSON.
for Example:
ToDictionary(ss => ss["subServiceName"].ToString(), ss => ss["status"].ToString()));

We have subServiceName as key  and value as status but i want status and description as values because if you will see my JSON then we have description also.

Comment: @user2911592 you can create value tuple for value (or introduce class): `ss => (status: ss["status"].ToString(), desc = ss["description"].ToString())`